# Detecting inherited user controls

Tags: c#, inheritance, user-controls

I am stuck in a bit of marsh here, as I can't figure out a simple enough way to detect inherited user controls.
Basically, I have a user control "UC",

```
public partial class UC : UserControl
```

which will work as a kind of template for common properties;

and some inherited user controls ("uc1","uc2","uc3", etc...)

```
public partial class uc1 : UC
```

*Purpose would be to list inherited controls and throw them in a container panel upon init.

**My question:** Can I detect/count/list them is some **simple** way (no 20+ line code stuff) or can it be done at all?

Any advice appreciated.

*Developer ir training :D*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (this will traverse all existing assemblies, not the ones that haven't already been loaded. I also recommend doing something more elegant than this which involves more awareness of what you actually need to be doing. This is just brute force (and it costs time and resources too so run this only once, not once every millisecond)):

```
var query = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where typeof(UC).IsAssignableFrom(type) && (type != typeof(UC))
            let ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
            where ctor != null
            select type;

foreach (var type in query) {                
    var control = Activator.CreateInstance(type, nonPublic: true) as UC;
    control.Parent = thePanel;
}
```

but beware of the logical flaw here: Each class that extends the `UC` class will have 1 instance and 1 instance only. Also: how will you dynamically manage the positioning of these user controls in inside `thePanel` ?

Comment: have you created a drag mechanism **at runtime** ? Please note that what I answered is something that happens **at runtime**. At design time you'll only see a blank panel, in the visual editor, awaiting guests (actually awaiting for the app to start running so that guest could arrive). Please also note that your question does not disambiguate things and common sense would dictate that you are speaking about what happens in the app, not in the IDE...

Comment: Drag mechanism is not yet done. A drag control will be added on UC, so all the inherited controls could have it.

Comment: ok, I tested this and it kind of enlists any control. This is a list of names it returned to text box for test purpose: Object
Control
ScrollableControl
ContainerControl
UserControl
Component

Comment: my mistake please check the latest edit where I changed `type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UC))` with `typeof(UC).IsAssignableFrom(type)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know, where these controls are located (I mean an assembly), you can use use `Reflection` to iterate through objects and test for the type.
Not sure if the resulting code will be 20 or less lines of code though, but it's the only way I know of...

Answer (score 0):

Add a static counter to the base class. in the base class common constructor, or init method - call counter++ . and on its closed event- call counter--.

If you are not affraid to write a few more lines of code, than a singleon pattern to hold the counter is better.

Comment: Without actually touching the subclasses their static constructors and initializers will never be executed (lazy class loading and jitting). That's why the counter will not be incremented correctly since I understand that Martins needs to "not do any specific stuff" with the subclasses...

Comment: The OP clearly says he wants to throw them on a panel upon Init. I think he wants to count instances and not types. However, a better approach will be to put the counter++ code in the base constructor, so I will edit my answer.